# This field is required. Error with ImageField and FileField on Django

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am new on Django, I am using Django 1.6.1 and in one of my form I get the next error

```
 This field is required.
```

I don't understand why I get this error, my form is very basic, so my Model, the statement who launch this error is form.is_valid(), but I don't know why. 
Some help would be apreciate.

my views is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = campoImagenForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        articulo = form.save(commit=False)
        articulo.item = item
        articulo.atributo = atributo
        articulo.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/workproject/' + str(project.id))
```

my Form is:

```
class campoImagenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = campoImagen
        fields = ('imagen',)
```

my Model is:

```
class campoImagen(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(ItemBase)
    atributo = models.ForeignKey(TipoItem)
    imagen = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Imagen', upload_to='archivos')
    version = models.IntegerField()
```

I don't have a clue of why I get such an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, in your model make your fields empty and nullable:

```
class campoImagen(models.Model):
    # [...]
    imagen = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Imagen', upload_to='archivos', null=True, blank=True)
```

Then in your model form alter the `required` parameter of your field:

```
class campoImagenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = campoImagen
        fields = ('imagen',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(campoImagenForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['imagen'].required = False
```

The model part is, however, obligatory. Otherwise you might be getting database inconsistency errors.

Keep in mind that [blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) and [null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) are different things. They do, however, work well together and should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In forms.py

```
class campoImagenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    imagen = forms.ImageField(verbose_name='Imagen', upload_to='archivos', required = False)
    class Meta:
        model = campoImagen
        fields = ('imagen',)
```